# Python script overwrite rows in Excel

Tags: python, excel

I have the following code:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
import sys
import os

string0="Username"
stringhost="Host"
string1="Last password change"
string2="Password expires"
string3="Password inactive"
string4="Account expires"
string5="Minimum number of days between password change"
string6="Maximum number of days between password change"
string7="Number of days of warning before password expires"
hostid="---"

workbook=xlsxwriter.Workbook('/media/sf_vboxshared/sample.xlsx')
worksheet1=workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
worksheet1.write(0,0,string0)
worksheet1.write(0,1,stringhost)
worksheet1.write(0,2,string1)
worksheet1.write(0,3,string2)
worksheet1.write(0,4,string3)
worksheet1.write(0,5,string4)
worksheet1.write(0,6,string5)
worksheet1.write(0,7,string6)
worksheet1.write(0,8,string7)

num1=1
num2=1
num3=1
num4=1
num5=1
num6=1
num7=1
num8=1
num9=1
contenttail=[]
with open("users.log",'r') as dump:
      for num, line in enumerate(dump):     
            if string1 in line: 
              tail=line.split(string1)[1]
              tail=tail.strip()
              tail=tail.lstrip(":")      
              worksheet1.write(num1,2,tail)
              num1=num1+1     
            elif string2 in line:
              tail2=line.split(string2)[1]
              tail2=tail2.strip()
              tail2=tail2.lstrip(":")
              worksheet1.write(num2,3,tail2)
              num2=num2+1
            elif string3 in line:
              tail=line.split(string3)[1]
              tail=tail.strip()
              tail=tail.lstrip(":")
              worksheet1.write(num3,4,tail)
              num3=num3+1
            elif string4 in line:
              tail=line.split(string4)[1]
              tail=tail.strip()
              tail=tail.lstrip(":")
              worksheet1.write(num4,5,tail)
              num4=num4+1
            elif string5 in line:
              tail=line.split(string5)[1]
              tail=tail.strip()
              tail=tail.lstrip(":")
              worksheet1.write(num5,6,tail)
              num5=num5+1
            elif string6 in line:
              tail=line.split(string6)[1]
              tail=tail.strip()
              tail=tail.lstrip(":")
              worksheet1.write(num6,7,tail)
              num6=num6+1
            elif string7 in line:
              tail=line.split(string7)[1]
              tail=tail.strip()
              tail=tail.lstrip(":")
              contenttail.append(tail)
              worksheet1.write(num7,8,tail)
              num7=num7+1
            elif hostid in line:
                   words=line.split(hostid)[1]
                   print words
                   contenthost=[]
                   contenthost.append(words)
                   num9=1
                   for i in range(0,len(contenthost)):
                     for num9 in range(num9,len(contenttail)):
                        worksheet1.write(num9,1,contenthost[i])
                        num9=num9+len(contenttail)
      content=[]
      with open("users.log",'r') as dump:
           for line in dump:
               content.append(line)
           for i in range(1, len(content),9):
              worksheet1.write(num8,0,content[i])
              num8=num8+1
workbook.close()
```

The idea of this script is to export data in Excel from one file called users.log.

users.log looks like this:

```
--- eq1
frank
Last password change                                    : Mar 05, 2018
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

mark
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

grand
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

system
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

syp
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

games
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

rob
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

gpod
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

gmail
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

news
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

qoop
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

proxy
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

data
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

backup
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7
--- eq2
newlist
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

dirk
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

mas
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

nobody
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

row
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

rag
Last password change                                    : Aug 03, 2016
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

minibus
Last password change                                    : Mar 05, 2018
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

cap
Last password change                                    : Mar 05, 2018
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

greg
Last password change                                    : Mar 05, 2018
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

vivid
Last password change                                    : Mar 05, 2018
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7

ntpd
Last password change                                    : Mar 05, 2018
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7
```

Code runs without error, but when it populates the column "1", it overwrites always the previous result. In column "1", "eq2" should start from the row where "eq1" finished +1. 
I think that the problem is with the appending to the contenthost list because for contenthost[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNzg7.jpg) I get list out of range and in contenthost[0] are listed both words. 
Any hint what it is wrong in the script?

UPDATE:

- With the list outside of the loop
  [image: With the list outside of the loop]
- With the list inside of the loop
  [image: With the list inside of the for loop]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `contenthost = []` initial declaration outside of the `for` loop and try again.

Comment: After trying this, I am getting in the Excel file the correct number of rows for eq1, but in the column it's written eq2. Eq2 where should be written is not written at all.

Comment: can you post your current output and your prior output? 
Its pretty hard to visualise without an example or picture. Thanks

Comment: I have attached two screenshots. Hope that now it's a little bit clear how it looks. My previous comment was not that accurate, but the screenshots are reflecting these two situations

Comment: what is the purpose of `contenttail`? It seems completely unnecessary and its probably the reason why your loop isn't working as intended. Try hardcoding the value first instead of relying on `len(contenttail)`, then figure out why you need `contenttail` to begin with and if its easier to just read another value to fill in the blank over there. 
Just looking at the code, it seems as though your `contenttail` is limiting the range and causing the eq2 to not appear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I am removing completely the `for num9 in range(num9,len(contenttail)):` I will have just one time eq1 and eq2 on their starting position. To be more specific: eq1 will fill just the cell B2 and eq2 will fill just the B16. Eq1 should fill the cells between B2 and B15 and Eq2 should fill the cells from B16 to B26. I would need a loop somehow to fill the rest of the empty spaces from B column for each eq.

Comment: I get your point, but the whole problem lies with your contenttail and appending using elif string7. Do a print (contenttail) and see what the value is. You'll figure out from there.